# How can I bundle data files with a Meteor application?

Tags: meteor

I need to bundle some data files (geoip data) with my meteor application. Simply putting the data files in my application directory doesn't appear to do anything - they're not copied to anywhere in `.meteor/local/build` when I run `meteor`.

How can I make meteor copy these files when it builds my application?

Comment: what do you intend to do with the files afterwards? If they are meant to be served statically, you need to put them into `/public`. If you access them from the app itself (programmatically), then I would recommend `/private` and opening them using the `Assets` object (http://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html).

Comment: It's used by https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip, so while I could hack the node-geoip source code, it would be nice to just be able to ship the data  in some fixed directory. It seems like I could put them in /private and then use `Assets.absoluteFilePath` to figure out the directory that they end up in

Answer (score 0):

So, files are loaded on different environment is a specific order. Have a look here for details on what's loaded where and when.

https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#load-order

Then you can decide where best to place the file depending on the use case.